# Deploy vue via gitlab ci to azure static web app (service)

Tags: azure, vue.js, gitlab-ci, azure-static-web-app

I already feel like kind of an idiot for asking this question - maybe I'm unable to google the right terms.
I want to archive a simple task - deploy a vue app via gitlab-ci to azure static web app (service).

Can anyone provide me some information / a ci script about it.
Otherwise I'm going the way through an Azure Devops Pipeline.

Comment: There are 2 ways to deploy vue static web apps on azure : with github actions and with azure devops. Are you asking about how to deploy through github actions?

Comment: Hei, no via gitlab - not GitHUB :)
Gitlab CI

Comment: Not Sure, hope this [blog post](https://faun.pub/automating-your-deployment-using-gitlab-azure-storage-static-website-hosting-75c767b2569f) helps you!

Comment: Thx. Already saw this one. But that is for storage blob and not for static web app (which is free)

Comment: @Fabian did you manage to deploy your vue app from gitlab to azure static web app? I found a tutorial for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/gitlab?tabs=vue), but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

Currently Azure Static Web Apps support deployment via GitHub Actions and Azure DevOps only.

Follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-devops) for deployment via Azure DevOps.